Why do the x86 32bit protected mode register not giving right value?
I have set 32 bit protected mode and try to load Global Descriptor table(GDT) by C and assembly and try to print the different registers value by check_gdt() function where
    void check_gdt() {
    uint16_t cs, ds, es, fs, gs, ss;

    // Inline assembly to get the values of segment registers
    asm volatile("mov %%cs, %0" : "=r"(cs));    
    asm volatile("mov %%ds, %0" : "=r"(ds));
    asm volatile("mov %%es, %0" : "=r"(es));
    asm volatile("mov %%fs, %0" : "=r"(fs));
    asm volatile("mov %%gs, %0" : "=r"(gs));
    asm volatile("mov %%ss, %0" : "=r"(ss));

    // Print the segment register values
    printf("CS: 0x%x\n", cs);
    printf("DS: 0x%x\n", ds);
    printf("ES: 0x%x\n", es);
    printf("FS: 0x%x\n", fs);
    printf("GS: 0x%x\n", gs);
    printf("SS: 0x%x\n", ss);
}

Initialize GDT by following
void initGdt(){
    gdt_ptr.limit = (sizeof(struct gdt_entry_struct) * 5) - 1;
    gdt_ptr.base = (uint32_t)&gdt_entries;

    setGdtGate(0,0,0,0,0);                      // Null segment                           _________________                   _______________
                                                // Explanation:                          |P|DPL|S|E|DC|RW|A|                 |G|DB|L|Res|    |
    setGdtGate(1,0,0xFFFFFFFF, 0x9A, 0xCF);     // Kernel code segment : access = 0x9A =>|1|00 |1|1|0 |1 |0|, gran = 0xCF => |1|1 |0|0  |1111|
    setGdtGate(2,0,0xFFFFFFFF, 0x92, 0xCF);     // Kernel data segment : access = 0x92 =>|1|00 |1|0|0 |1 |0|, gran = 0xCF => |1|1 |0|0  |1111|                  
                                                //                                        _________________                   _______________
    setGdtGate(3,0,0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFA, 0xCF);     // User code segment   : access = 0xFA =>|1|11 |1|1|0 |1 |0|, gran = 0xCF => |1|1 |0|0  |1111|
    setGdtGate(4,0,0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF2, 0xCF);     // User data segment   : access = 0x9A =>|1|11 |1|0|0 |1 |0|, gran = 0xCF => |1|1 |0|0  |1111|
                                                //                                        -----------------                   ---------------
    gdt_flush((uint32_t) &gdt_ptr);
}



void setGdtGate(uint32_t num, uint32_t base, uint32_t limit, uint8_t access, uint8_t gran){

    gdt_entries[num].base_low = (base & 0xFFFF);        // Assign lower base 16 bit
    gdt_entries[num].base_middle = (base >> 16) & 0xFF; // Assign middle base 8 bit
    gdt_entries[num].base_high = (base >> 24) & 0xFF;   // Assign higher base 8 bit

    gdt_entries[num].limit_low = (limit & 0xFFFF);      // Assign lower limit 16 bit
    gdt_entries[num].flags = (limit >> 16) & 0x0F;      // Assign flags lower 4 bit
    gdt_entries[num].flags |= (gran & 0xF0);            // Assign flags upper 4 bit

    gdt_entries[num].access = access;                   // Assign access 8 bit
}

and loading GDT in CPU by gdt_flush function
gdt_flush:
    ; [esp] Return address (from CALL)
    ; Load the address of the GDT descriptor
    MOV eax, [esp + 4]  ; To load the content of [esp+4] address which is the first argument of gdt_flush((uint32_t) &gdt_ptr)
    LGDT [eax]      ; Load the GDT into the CPU

    MOV ax, 0x10    ; Load kernel data segment selector (0x10)
    MOV ds, ax      ; Set data segment register to kernel data segment
    MOV es, ax      ; Set extra segment register to kernel data segment
    MOV fs, ax      ; Set general-purpose segment to kernel data segment
    MOV gs, ax      ; Set general-purpose segment to kernel data segment
    MOV ss, ax      ; Set stack segment to kernel data segment

    JMP 0x08:.flush ;Far jump to selector 0x08 (code segment) and the address of flush
                    ; Entry 1: Kernel code segment (selector = 0x08)

.flush:
    RET

I am expecting from above gdt loading
CS : 0x08
DS : 0x10
ES : 0X10
FS : 0X10
GS : 0X10
SS : 0X10

But why do I am getting wrong result like below?


Sounds like your printf is broken. Notice that you have uint16_t which can not possibly hold the values shown.

Could be a number of things. Does your printf function actually work. Have you tries to use GDB along with QEMU to debug your code? In QEMU if you want to see what the real state of the segment registers are... while you have this up on the screen in QEMU enter the QEMU monitor with Control-Alt-2. Then issue the command info registers. That should dump the CPU register state including the segment selector values. I find it interesting that the printf prints out the value you are looking for followed by other stuff. Did you properly NUL terminate the buffer with the string value?

The "x86 32bit protected mode register" is always "giving right value".  It may not be what you expected, but it is always right.

Yes @Jester and @
Michael Petch both are right my printf function was broken.
I am using print_hex(cs) ... works fine where print_hex in vga.c is
    // Outputs a hexadecimal number to the screen.
void print_hex(uint32_t n) {
    char hex_chars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    print("0x");

    for (int i = 28; i >= 0; i -= 4) // process each nibble (4 bits)
    {
        putchar(hex_chars[(n >> i) & 0xF]);
    }
}


You could make hex_chars static const so the compiler could more easily avoid generating code to copy it to the stack.  Other than that, this looks fine.
